# Saving Android SurfaceView to Bitmap and some elements are missing

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

I have my SurfaceView up and running with a button to open the camera and take a picture which is used as the background and another button to add items that sit on top and can be moved around. This all works fine until I try to save the SurfaceView as a Bitmap when all I get is the background and none of the images on top.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(_mGotImage){

        canvas.drawBitmap(_mImage, 0, 0, null);
    }else{

            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    //if the array is not empty
    if(!_mJazzItems.isEmpty()){

        //step through each item in the array
        for(JazzItem item: _mJazzItems){

            //get the bitmap it is using
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), item.getBitmap());
            //and draw that bitmap at its X and Y coords
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, item.getX(), item.getY(), null);

        }
    }
}
```

This is the method called to try and save the Canvas.

```
    public void screenGrab(){

    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(_mPanelWidth, _mPanelHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    this.onDraw(canvas);

    String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test2.png";
    File file = new File(path);

    try{

        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();

    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The onDraw works fine, I get my camera shot in the background and can add all my items over the top and move them around. Just when I try to get a screen shot, none of the items on top are present.

Thanks for any help!!

-- UPDATE --

I have modified the screen grab method to this:

```
    public void screenGrab(){

    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(_mPanelWidth, _mPanelHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);

    canvas.drawBitmap(_mImage, 0, 0, null);

    //if the array is not empty
    if(!_mJazzItems.isEmpty()){

        //step through each item in the array
        for(JazzItem item: _mJazzItems){

            //get the bitmap it is using
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), item.getBitmap());
            //and draw that bitmap at its X and Y coords
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, item.getX(), item.getY(), null);

        }
    }

    String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test2.png";
    File file = new File(path);

    try{

        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();

    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can't see why this is not drawing the other images over the top...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case i am using this:

```
public static Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap overLayImage, Context con) {
    Bitmap cs = null;
    int width, height = 0;
    width     = c.getWidth();
    height     = c.getHeight();
    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0, 0, null);
    String left = yourleftPosition;
    String top = yourtopPosition;

    comboImage.drawBitmap(overLayImage, Float.parseFloat(left), Float.parseFloat(top),null);
    /******
    *
    * Write file to SDCard
    *
    * ****/
    String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        String pathis = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/DCIM/Camera/" + tmpImg;
        os = new FileOutputStream(pathis);
        cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e);
    }
    return cs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try some changes now.